# Can BFMatcher be used to self-created descriptor

Tags: opencv

The old BruteForceMatcher from OpenCV 2.2.0 can be used to self-created descriptor. 
Does the BFMatcher from OpenCV2.4.1 support any dimensional descriptor?

```
  BFMatcher descriptorMatcher12(NORM_L1), descriptorMatcher21(NORM_L1);
  vector<DMatch> matches12, matches21;
  descriptorMatcher12.match(feature1, feature2, matches12); 
  descriptorMatcher21.match(feature2, feature1, matches21);
```

there is an exception when executing `descriptorMatcher12.match()`.

thanks